# Return first encountered result in scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

> **Problem Statement:**

After parsing, I'm sending each URL to parse_links to extract email address from it.

After parsing, I want to stop iteration if I found the email address from that link and return the result.

**i.e.**

> In loop suppose there are 2 URLs: **example.com/contact** and **example.com/about**
>
> If email address found from **example.com/contact** then I don't want to scrap the second one. But I'm getting the email address from all links.

**Here's my code:**

```
def parse(self, response):
    urls = [
        instance.url for instance in LinkExtractor(
            allow_domains='example.com'
        ).extract_links(response)
    ]

    for url in sorted(urls, reverse=True):
        request = Request(url, callback=self.parse_links)
        yield request

def parse_links(self, response):
    item = EmailScraperItem()
    mailrex = '[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+'
    result = response.xpath('//a[@href]').re('%s' % mailrex)
    if result:
        item['emails'] = result  # here how can I send first value and ignore other results
    return item
```

After running crawler I'm getting this output:

```
2017-01-30 20:31:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://example.com/contact/>
{'emails': ['abc@example.com']}  # first result

2017-01-30 20:31:29 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://example.com/about/>
{'emails': ['xyz@example.com']}  # second result
```

**I want only first one.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to asynchronous nature of Scrapy you can't be even sure that responses will come to the callback in the same order as they were emitted. What you can do is to get urls list, pass it with `meta`, and visit urls sequentially like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    urls = [
        instance.url for instance in LinkExtractor(
            allow_domains='example.com'
        ).extract_links(response)
    ]

    try:
       # take url and pass remaining to the callback
       return Request(urls.pop(), callback=self.parse_links, meta={'urls': urls})
    except IndexError:
       pass

def parse_links(self, response):
    item = EmailScraperItem()
    mailrex = '[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+'
    result = response.xpath('//a[@href]').re('%s' % mailrex)
    if result:
        item['emails'] = result  # here how can I send first value and ignore other results
        return item
    # if no emails found, request next url from list
    try:
       urls = response.meta['urls']
       return Request(urls.pop(), callback=self.parse_links, meta={'urls': urls})
    except IndexError:
       pass
```

Comment: Your approach worked like a charm! Thanks, @mizhgun!